# Receive json by API with OAuth2

Tags: windows, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

I have an application where I receive JSON data. My application is a web service written as an ASP.NET Web API (running on the .NET framework). My application lives on a Windows server.

I have used Azure Devops to create an application to get App ID, app secret and client secret. Now my problem is that I don't really know how to implement OAuth2 on my application to get the OAuth2 to start working.

I have tried different code examples like: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc-oauth-2-0-rest-web-api-authorization-using-database-first-approach/ but I don't have MVC.

I have also tried following these steps but I don't really know what to implement in my code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/azure-devops-oauth?view=azure-devops#scopes